# Error about a MVC4 asp.net login app after publishing to azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I build a small login app following the video here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7RoJIgRcuOc&list=PLt2cGgt6G8Wo8CoYLGX31mbHU4L-Erpkg

I created the database first and then used this database to create the entity framework to make me get the content from the database. Then I added a small hash to the process of the validation of password. Below is the code of my user controller.

```
namespace LogInSystem.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        public const int SALT_BYTE_SIZE = 24;
        public const int HASH_BYTE_SIZE = 24;
        public const int PBKDF2_ITERATIONS = 1000;
        //
        // GET: /User/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult LogIn()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LogIn(Models.UserModel user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (IsValid(user.Email, user.Password))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Email, false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login data is incorrect");
                }
            }
            return View(user); 
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Registration()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Registration(Models.UserModel user)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using(var db = new MainDbEntities())
                {
                    var sysUser = db.SystemUsers.Create();

                    // create salt and password hash
                    RNGCryptoServiceProvider csprng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
                    byte[] salt = new byte[SALT_BYTE_SIZE];
                    csprng.GetBytes(salt);

                    byte[] hash = PBKDF2(user.Password, salt, PBKDF2_ITERATIONS, HASH_BYTE_SIZE);

                    sysUser.Email = user.Email;
                    sysUser.Password = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
                    sysUser.PasswordSalt = Convert.ToBase64String(salt);
                    sysUser.UserId = Guid.NewGuid();

                    db.SystemUsers.Add(sysUser);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult LogOut()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        private bool IsValid (string email, string password)
        {
            bool isValid = false;

            using (var db = new MainDbEntities())
            {
                var user = db.SystemUsers.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Email == email);

                if(user != null)
                {
                    byte[] salt = Convert.FromBase64String(user.PasswordSalt);

                    byte[] correctHash = Convert.FromBase64String(user.Password);

                    byte[] testHash = PBKDF2(password, salt, PBKDF2_ITERATIONS, correctHash.Length);

                    if(SlowEquals(correctHash, testHash))
                    {
                        isValid = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            return isValid;
        }

        // compute the hash of a password using PBKDF2-SHA1
        private byte[] PBKDF2(string password, byte[] salt, int iterations, int outputBytes) 
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt);
            pbkdf2.IterationCount = iterations;
            return pbkdf2.GetBytes(outputBytes);
        }

        // Compare two byte arrays
        private bool SlowEquals(byte[] a, byte [] b) 
        {
            uint diff = (uint)a.Length ^ (uint)b.Length;
            for(int i = 0; i < a.Length && i < b.Length; i++) 
            {
                diff |= (uint)(a[i] ^ b[i]);
            }
            return diff == 0;
        }
    }
}
```

After that, I wanted to publish the app to azure. I checked a lot of methods. I tried to create from the azure side. I created the website and the server. Then I created a database in that server. I copied the connect string to the web.config. I also tried to publish from the Visual Studio, it was still not working. Here is the connect string in my web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-LogInSystem-20140626152022;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-LogInSystem-20140626152022.mdf" />
<add name="MainDbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MainDbModel.csdl|res://*/MainDbModel.ssdl|res://*/MainDbModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\MainDb.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

When I tried to register every time. It would go to the shared error. I was confused and don't know how to solve this.

Here is the context.cs

```
public partial class MainDbEntities : DbContext
{
    public MainDbEntities()
        : base("name=MainDbEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public DbSet<SystemUsers> SystemUsers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking about. You say "it does not work". What does not work? and how it does not work? and what do you expect from _it_?

Comment: Are you trying to use localdb on azure?  As I don't think that'll work - you'll need to point your app to an Azure SQL database.

Comment: Are you saying that PUBLISH failed or that after you successfully publish to Azure then the site does not work as expected?

Comment: When the app is working locally, I could register and log in, I could see the change and the information I just registered in the local database. But after I published it to the azure, when I tried to register, it would just pop up the shared mistake, says, An error occurred while processing your request. I tried to change the connect string once. But it didn't work, perhaps I didn't change it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Right now your connection string is targeting to local db, modify it for azure like

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=SERVER_NAME;Database=DATABASE_NAME;User ID=USER_ID;Password=PASSWORD;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

after setting your connection string look into your dbContext to check if it's pointing to right connection string. Your dbContext should be like

```
public class YourContext : DbContext
{
    public YourContext() : base("DefaultConnection"){ }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this. But what about the MainDbEntities. Should I use this to connect the database. I will put my context below.

Comment: @Apple This connection string should also point to right database, but i am not sure that where you are using this connectionstrinf. Please provide some code